# Jquery Hover not working in Firefox or IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm new to Javascript/Jquery so go easy!

I've created what will be an HTML facebook tab, with some images and applied a hover effect so that they expand as the mouse hovers over. This seems to work fine in Chrome but in Firefox and IE it's glitchy and the animation seems to run repeatedly unless the cursor is dead centre over the image.

I've tried adding "stop()" in there but either it doesn't work or I'm putting it in the wrong place (probably the latter). If anyone has any suggestions I would be very grateful!

```
  <script>
  $(document).ready(function() {

    $('.circle').hover(function() {

        $(this).animate({
            'position' : 'relative',
            'width' : 120,
            'height' : 120,
            'border-radius' : 60,
            'margin' : 20,
            'top' : 0,

        });

    }, function() {

        $(this).animate({
            'position' : 'relative',
            'width' : 100,
            'height' : 100,
            'margin' : 25,
            'top' : 10,
        });

    });

});
</script>
```

Full example available here:

http://careers.dept.shef.ac.uk/Facebook/FacebookTab.html

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Where is your function? Can you post some js/jquery. Or point to it in your site.

Comment: Hi the link to the html file is included above. The jquery is included in that. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

> You can use e.stoppropagation() function to stop bubbling.
>
> Eg.[stoppropagation](http://jsfiddle.net/jonathon/JLMaR/)

```
    <div id="noStop">
    <span>This one doesn't stop bubbling</span>
    <ul></ul>
   </div>
    <div id="stop">
    <span>This one stops bubbling</span>
    <ul></ul>
     </div>
```

Comment: Hi thanks for your response. I've tried this but it doesn't seem to make any difference.